# F# filtering a list (newbie)

Tags: f#

I'm recently new to f# so please bear with me. the problem i have is I'm trying to display only yo parts of a list but unsure of the coding for example

int * int * float * float * int * float * float =

but only want

int * int

any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be useful if you gave us a concrete example of what you're trying to do or an F# snippet of what you have so far...

Comment: Check if you're not confusing a tuple with a list. The type you cite is downright scary.

Answer (score 1):

So one way would be

```
l |> List.map (fun (a,b,_,_,_,_,_) -> (a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you presented:

```
int * int * float * float * int * float * float
```

is a signature of a tuple. It means your tuple has 7 items of `float` and `int` type in the order specified in the signature. So an example of it would be:

```
let myTuple = (2, 4, 6.0, 8.0, 10, 12.0, 14.0)
```

You can create a function to extract first two items and ignore remaining ones.

```
let frstAndScd (a, b, _, _, _, _, _) = (a, b)
```

The underscore means that you are not interested in these items. You only take those marked by letters and return them as a new tuple.